# Referencing root parent of variable in singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, singleton, object-literal

If i am inside hello.world.planet and i reference this.two, that will get siblings, how can i reference hello.planet without referring to the name of the variable, something similar to 'this'

```
var hello = {
    world: {
        one: {
        },
        two: {
        },
        three: {
        }
    },
    planet: {
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `var that = hello.world;` and use `that` instead of `hello.world;` .

Comment: "*If i am inside hello.world.planet*" - `planet` is no property of `hello.world`, did you mean `one`? Also, none of these are functions, so what do you mean by "*inside*"?

Comment: You can't be inside of that, `world` object doesn't have `planet` property. As the object doesn't have any method, you can't use `this` keyword.

Comment: You cannot. There's nothing wrong with referring to it via the `hello` variable though. If you need something that works like `this` (i.e. depending on the call context), you mustn't use a nested object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely following where you want to make a reference, but you could try using .bind(). I hope this is what you're after to:

```
var hello = {
    world: {
        one: {
        },
        two: function() {
            alert(this.planet);
        }.bind(hello),
        three: {
        }
    },
    planet: {
    }
}
```